# Error with Importing data using pirls.select.merge() in intsvy library

Tags: r

Utilizing PIRLS 2015 datasets, I'm trying to regress seven independent variables(Teacher SPSS file) on five plausible values (Students' SPSS file). When trying to use the following code:

```
dir1 <- "~/Dropbox/PIRLS2015Data"

pirls1 <- pirls.select.merge(folder= dir1,
                             countries= 682, 
                              student= c("IDSCHOOL", "ASRREA"), 
                            #home= c("ASDHEDUP", "ASDHOCCP", "ASDHELA", "ASBHELA"),
                            school= c("IDSCHOOL", "ATBR10"))
```

I receive an error message stating
 "Error in intsvy.select.merge(folder = folder, countries = countries, student = student,  :  cannot locate student data files".

How can I merge several variables from different SPSS files using pirls.select.merge()?

Comment: You could also try the `RALSA` package which has a graphical user interface: https://cran.r-project.org/package=RALSA For guides on how to use it, see here: http://ralsa.ineri.org/user-guide/

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should adjust your data path as below;

```
dir1 = "/Dropbox/PIRLS2015Data"
```

then, you must to print of data of pirls2015 like below

```
pirls.var.label(folder=dir1, 
               school.file="School.sav", 
               student.file="Student.sav",
               parent.file="Parent.sav")
```

after overall you can use " pirls.select.merge"